# Passing optional parameter to JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I have an issue with JdbcTemplate when passing parameters objects with null reference.

Given that I have the following test data:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (1,'TEST')");
jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (2,'TEST_2')");
jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (3, NULL)");
```

Following code doesn't retrieve anything:

```
String contentArg = null;
List<Entity> entityList_3 = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE CONTENT = ?", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Entity.class), contentArg);
```

Is there any way I could fix this, just using JdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle NVL function to support optional parameter:

```
 WHERE CONTENT = NVL(?, CONTENT) "
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately we don't use Oracle database. We have SOLID (from IBM) and as far as I know they don't have NVL.

Comment: @Cristi maybe you can use decode function https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_decode.html

Comment: There is no DECODE function.

Comment: Error: [Solid JDBC 7.0.0.0 Build 2011-10-14] SOLID SQL Error 51: non-existent function 'DECODE'
SQLState:  HY000
ErrorCode: 51

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve this by modifying the query.

In my case, I was using IBM solidDb and the fix contains in using IFNULL function.

```
AND IFNULL(CONTENT,'') = IFNULL(?,'')
```